# Сортировка таблицы по значениям из другой таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Имеется 2 таблицы `oc_product` и `oc_product_option_value`

структура `oc_product { product_id, name, price, image и т.д.}`

структура `oc_product_option_value { product_id, price, quantity, и т.д. }`

Проблема в том, что в CMS есть сортировка по цене, которая сортирует по цене в таблице `oc_product`, а там цена у всех товаров у которых есть размеры равна 0. Цена для каждого размера хранится в таблице `oc_product_option_value` с привязкой по `product_id`, но проблема в том что у 1 товара может быть до 5 размеров. Мне нужно извлечь данные из таблицы `oc_product` и сортировать их по минимальному для каждого id'шника значению `price` в таблице `oc_product_option_value`

Надеюсь у меня получилось максимально понятно объяснить проблему, надеюсь что это можно как-то сделать через  sql запрос.

Comment: типа _"цена от ..."_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select o.*, ov.price1 from oc_product o
join
(select product_id, min(price) as price1 
from oc_product_option_value ov
group by product_id) 
ov on o.product_id = ov.product_id
order by ov.price1
```

А процедурного расширения в MySQL нет? Можно было бы просто функцию сделать, которая бы возвращала минимальную цену по product_id.

Comment: Если подзапрос материализуется (что возможно) - тормоза-а-а...

Comment: Можно было бы на таблицу oc_product_option_value повесить триггер, который бы в таблице oc_product обновлял поле price. Тогда бы все свелось к select * from oc_product, быстрее не бывает :)

Comment: *Можно было бы на таблицу oc_product_option_value повесить триггер* Только при условии отсутствия каскадных операций... что для такой таблицы при правильном построении схемы БД несколько сомнительно.